# Load testing with different IE versions

Tags: performance, jmeter, loadrunner

I don't know if this question makes much sense but i would like to know if load testing can be done on different IE versions. For instance my product supports IE 8, 9 , 10.... Please clarify more on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When we do load testing, we are more interested in knowing the server performance. Not the client's browser performance.

JMeter itself acts like a browser. It sends the Http request & once it gets the response, it can display it like a browser(it does not execute javascript files though. It makes sense because javascript is going to be executed in client's machine.)

So, for your question, JMeter is not a tool for your requirement. You may have a look at the `httpwatch` which shows the page load time for the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This only makes sense if

1. You build pages dynamically based upon browser type and version
2. If your load for your exceptional condition on page generation, which is typically early versions of IE, is significant

Answer (score 0):

Simulating different browser versions is not always a requirement is performance testing, but could be needed in specific case. Do it if it really makes sense to do.

There are commercial tools which can easily simulate the different browser types/versions like LoadRunner, Microsoft Visual Studio etc. If you are going to use open source, trying mimicing the scenarios by providing browser details/properties in user agents header etc., just like the actual browser sends. You can capture this by checking the request headers from the browser (press F12 on chrome and see network)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do with JMeter is adding a [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send different `User-Agent` header value for each Internet Explorer versions. You can refer [Understanding user-agent strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx) guide to see user agent values for different IE versions, however I don't think it will provide the full picture as JMeter doesn't actually "render" page.

So I would go the following way:

1. Use JMeter to put your server under expected load
2. Use one [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) instance per Internet Explorer version to perform real browser testing of the system when it's under JMeter's load to measure performance differences.